# react-native-google-places-autocomplete not working on React native 0.61

Tags: android, ios, react-native, google-places-api, google-places-autocomplete

I have added react-native-google-places-autocomplete with yarn in my react-native cli project but it is not working. Here are the issues I am facing at the moment.

1. the places drop down is not showing up on IOS, however the input text field allows me to enter a place name but the predictions list does not appear
2. onPress handler is not triggered at all on both IOS and android
3. The Text Input coming from react-native-google-places-autocomplete does not allow me to enter anything on ANDROID. It is like disabled all the time ( although the focus is set to true)

Note: all google location apis are enabled , google maps api, places api and geocode api are enabled and a valid api key is given.

I tried all possible solutions available including the following:

1. setting zIndex: 1000 a high value to avoid it being hidden behind some other view
2. Tried creating new RN App and added only this component to keep the project clean
3. Regenerating the API and even using another api which works with previous versions of REACT NATIVE.

The logs don't show anything on both Xcode and Android Studio. Here is the code snippet:

```
        <View style = {[{zIndex: 2, backgroundColor: 'white'}]}>
                <GooglePlacesAutocomplete
                    ref = {ref => setSearchTextRef(ref)}
                    placeholder='Search for gym'
                    styles={{
                        container: {backgroundColor: 'transparent'},
                        textInputContainer: styles.viewStyle,
                        textInput: styles.textInputStyle,
                    }}
                    keyboardShouldPersistTaps = {'handled'}
                    listUnderlayColor = {'transparent'}
                    textInputProps = {{
                        onFocus: () => focusInput(),
                        onBlur: () => blurInput(),
                        onChangeText: (text) => onChange(text)
                    }}
                    minLength={1} // minimum length of text to search
                    returnKeyType={'search'}
                    listViewDisplayed={'auto'}   // true/false/undefined
                    fetchDetails={true}
                    renderDescription={row => row.description} // custom description render
                    onPress={(data, details = null) => {
                        let coordinates = details.geometry.location;
                        sendCoordinates(coordinates, {data, details});
                    }}
                    getDefaultValue={() => ''}
                    query={{
                        key: googleAPIKey,
                        language: 'en', // language of the results
                        // types: '(cities)' // default: 'geocode'
                    }}
                    nearbyPlacesAPI='GooglePlacesSearch' // Which API to use: GoogleReverseGeocoding or GooglePlacesSearch
                    GooglePlacesSearchQuery={{
                        rankby: 'distance',
                        types: 'gym'
                    }}
                    filterReverseGeocodingByTypes={['locality', 'administrative_area_level_3']} 
                    debounce={200}
                />
            </View>
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2):

Your code with a few things commented out worked for me. Commented out your function calls since those were not provided.

```
      <View style = {[{zIndex: 2, backgroundColor: 'white'}]}>
          <GooglePlacesAutocomplete
              //ref = {ref => setSearchTextRef(ref)}
              placeholder='Search for gym'
              styles={{
                  container: {backgroundColor: 'transparent'},
                  //textInputContainer: styles.viewStyle,
                  //textInput: styles.textInputStyle,
              }}
              keyboardShouldPersistTaps = {'handled'}
              listUnderlayColor = {'transparent'}
              textInputProps = {{
                  //onFocus: () => focusInput(),
                  //onBlur: () => blurInput(),
                  //onChangeText: (text) => onChange(text)
              }}
              minLength={1} // minimum length of text to search
              returnKeyType={'search'}
              listViewDisplayed={'auto'}   // true/false/undefined
              fetchDetails={true}
              renderDescription={row => row.description} // custom description render
              onPress={(data, details = null) => {
                  let coordinates = details.geometry.location;
                  console.log(JSON.stringify(details)); //display details in console!
                  //sendCoordinates(coordinates, {data, details});
              }}
              getDefaultValue={() => ''}
              query={{
                key: 'YourKeyHere',
                language: 'en', // language of the results
                  // types: '(cities)' // default: 'geocode'
              }}
              nearbyPlacesAPI='GooglePlacesSearch' // Which API to use: GoogleReverseGeocoding or GooglePlacesSearch
              GooglePlacesSearchQuery={{
                  rankby: 'distance',
                  types: 'gym'
              }}
              filterReverseGeocodingByTypes={['locality', 'administrative_area_level_3']} 
              debounce={200}
          />
      </View>
```

Answer (score 0):

This was happening to me because I had this control inside ScrollView.
Using keyboardShouldPersistTaps="handled" on ScrollView seems to fix it

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please edit to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.

After all the solutions i tried nothing was working. Even though I had everything completed even the billing configuration on the google APIs, the the places drop down just wasn't showing.

So at start I reinstalled GooglePlacesAutocomplete with *"yarn add react-native-google-places-autocomplete"*, if you have npm do the *"npm i react-native-google-places-autocomplete"*.

Then I added these two imports again from the start:

import { GooglePlacesAutocomplete } from "react-native-google-places-autocomplete";
import { GOOGLE_MAPS_APIKEY } from "@env";

Then  I  rewrote GooglePlacesAutocomplete & GOOGLE_MAPS_APIKEY in my code:

```
<GooglePlacesAutocomplete
          placeholder="Where From?"
          styles={{
            container: {
              flex: 0,
            },
            textInput: {
              fontSize: 18,
            },
          }}
          query={{
            key: GOOGLE_MAPS_APIKEY,
            language: "en",
          }}
          nearbyPlacesAPI="GooglePlacesSearch"
          debounce={200}
        />
```

so they define the *"new imports"* and do the command *"yarn install"* on my project file even though it was already up to date.

Lastly, I restart my project with clean cache using the command *"expo r -c"*.
Magically, it worked!

Hope, that helps someone in the future!

Answer (score -6):

This package is no longer maintained and simply not working. I tried on IOS with expo. I didn't even get a list of results. I found a other package that is working like a charm:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-places-input

Comment: The above package is maintained.  There was a release 10 days ago for it. Convenient that you are saying its not maintained while pushing your own package.

Comment: A bit of a scummy move sir